# Como ajustar legenda com dublagem em um Beat Em´Up no Unity?

Tags: unity3d, unity-5

Alguém poderia me ajudar como colocar uma dublagem (diálogo) dentro de uma cena em um game Beat em´Up?
Meu personagem percorre o jogo e quando encontra o Boss fala alguma coisa, no caso eu gostaria de colocar o áudio da fala junto com a legenda. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Olá, bem vindo ao SOPT. Este site não é um fórum, então por favor faça o [tour] e leia [ask] se ainda não fez. :) Bom, o que vc já tentou? O que você quer fazer pode ter vários níveis de complexidade, desde um simples áudio sendo tocado juntamente com uma animação até o famoso lip syncing (que, aliás, pode ser feito manualmente por um animador ou até mesmo estimado a partir de análise de áudio). Qual exatamente é a sua necessidade? É só sincronizar a legenda com o áudio, ou tem também animações? Edite a pergunta e forneça mais detalhes.

Comment: Enquanto isso, na sala de justiça, eu sugiro vc dar uma olhada nessa Asset gratuita e muito boa, utilizada justamente pra fazer diálogos textuais: http://fungusgames.com Pode ser que já te ajude, já que ela tem opções para sincronizar áudio.